# How can I add custom fields in variable Woocommerce products, available for all the variations?

Tags: woocommerce

I need to create some custom field for my variable products in Woocommerce.
These fields has to equal for all the variations, so I would like to add them as general data, I don't want to insert these data for each variation.

I tried to add custom field for the variations,like here: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-custom-field-product-variation/
but in this way I need to add them separately for each variation

I also tried adding them as general data, like here:
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-product-fields-woocommerce/
but they don't show up when I select "variable product"

Comment: _"I also tried adding them as general data"_ **->** In WooCommerce, the general tab is not available (visible) for a variable product, except when taxes enabled. Under WooCommerce > Settings > General > Enable taxes.